# known the result of linear transformation, find the general linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$.

 If $T \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -5\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $T \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ -4 \end{pmatrix}$,

 then find $T \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}, \forall \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Notice that
$$(0,1)^T=-\frac12(1,0)^T+\frac12(1,2)^T$$
so

$$(x,y)^T=\left(x-\frac12\right)(1,0)^T+\left(y+\frac12\right)(1,2)^T$$
and use the fact that $T$ is linear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that the $i$-th column of $T$ is the result of the application of $T$ on the $i$-th base vector. So, you already have the result of
$$T\left(\array{1\\0}\right)$$
and you can see that 
$$\left(\array{0\\1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\array{1\\2}\right)-\left(\array{1\\0}\right)\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

For all $\;\binom xy\in\Bbb R^2\;$

$$\binom xy=\frac y2\binom12+\left(x-\frac y2\right)\binom10\implies$$

$$T\binom xy=\frac y2T\binom12+\left(x-\frac y2\right)T\binom10=complete$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $T = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}$.

This gives you the system of equations.
\begin{align}
a + 2b &= -5 \\
c + 2d &= 1 \\
a &= 3 \\
c &= -4.
\end{align}

Solving, we get
$T = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -4\\
-4 & \frac{5}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$

So, $\boxed{T\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3x - 4y \\ -4x + \frac{5}{2}y
\end{pmatrix}.}$

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to find 
$T \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $T \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, because then (by linearity), for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$T \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}= xT\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+yT\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

You already have $T \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. 
$T \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(T \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}-T\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\Big)=\begin{pmatrix} -4\\ 5/2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You mean $T \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}= xT\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+yT\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$